# Multiple instances of same vf component on a Visualforce page. Data members value becomes null

Tags: visualforce

I am using same pagination_component multiple times on a visualforce page. But on this page only that component works fine which loaded at last.

First time when my page loads all component values show correct on my screen. But as i click on any navigation button it gives an error

> Attempt to de-reference a null object.

The reason is that component where I clicked component controller's variable/data member's (`public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;`) values become null. May be because of reloading constructor but i am using rerender.

When i checked each component associated data member values what i get is only one component has associated values remaining places(where same component multiple time) all data-members become null. So is there any way to handle it or I have to re-execute my code where I am initializing all data members.

I have also append id's in my action function name and at calling point to differentiate methods.

```
      <apex:actionFunction name="first{!CompID}" action="{!first}" reRender="lst" oncomplete="hideLoading();"/>
      <apex:actionFunction name="previous{!CompID}" action="{!previous}" reRender="lst" oncomplete="hideLoading();"/>
      <apex:actionFunction name="next{!CompID}" action="{!next}" reRender="lst" oncomplete="hideLoading();"/>
      <apex:actionFunction name="last{!CompID}" action="{!last}" reRender="lst" oncomplete="hideLoading();"/>
      <apex:actionFunction name="callsetMethod{!CompID}" action="{!afterLoad}" reRender="lst" oncomplete="hideLoading();"/>
```

Thanks in advance for your answers or any suggestions.

Comment: I can appreciate your frustration but this is hard to understand and could benefit from a simple code example that reproduces the issue using the minimum of elements, see [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Thanks @cropredy, I figure out the issue. As I added 2 or more times same component on one vf page. So for each component constructor executing 2 times, don't know why. So when second time constructor executes all data members value becomes null. Solution: created a method, put my initialization code in that and call this method from any getter/ get method of data members.

Comment: Great!  post that as an answer.